# Newbie in VNC Remote Desktop Access - I needs help to set it up

Tags: server, remote-desktop, vnc

I'd be a great help if I could access my mom's (I think windows) computer via Remote Desktop Access. I've been at the other end at my work, but how do I do it myself?

I have Remmina, I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS - it asks for a server when following this [guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/access-remote-desktop#3-add-a-connection). How can I set that up for free/the cheapest and easiest way, that is still safe?

Answer (score 0):

> for free/the cheapest and easiest way

###### Use third-party software

In my opinion, the cheapest and easiest way to remotely connect devices between different networks is through third-party software, and this type of software is already quite common.

- For example, I often use **[sunlogin](https://sunlogin.oray.com/en/embed/software.html)** and **[teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/solutions/remote-desktop/linux/)** in my daily work, but otherwise you can also get other types of software by googling

If you use software such as **Remmina**, you also need to provide the address, such as: `a public IP address:service remote port` (usually is the port of Remmina).

look at [the picture of the second step](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/access-remote-desktop#2-launch-remmina). the remote address is a VPS server

> that is still safe

For security purpose, you can buy a cloud server on aliyun, aws or even google cloud.

- at this time, you can open the specified port manually(usually ssh service, and Remmina's port) by [using the security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules.html)), in order to be safe from hackers' attacks from regular ports.

###### Use your own built server

you can use [openvpn](https://openvpn.net/), [frp](https://github.com/fatedier/frp) and other open source software to build your own vpn, making your network at work interoperable with your home network, so that you can remote to your home windows computer

In short, you need to put your home's network and your work computer in the same network environment (or be able to connect), and then everything will become easy.